# Rolling back updates in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I signed onto the EAP program, and now I am facing a lot of problems. Is there any way to revert back to 2.7.2 instead of staying with 2.7.3? How can I roll back updates. When I try to search for this, I just get VCS links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reinstall the latest [release version from the official site](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html). There is also [a page with even older releases](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Previous+PyCharm+Releases).

It's the only way to go back to the older version.

PyCharm 2.7.3 will be released soon, you should [report the issues you faced](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), otherwise you will still have them in the 2.7.3 release version.